# Application not starting, manually

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store

I am developing an iPhone application which works perfectly when doing a build & run, it runs like a charm.

But after I exited the app which ran from the build & run, an I try to start it manually by pressing the app icon on the phone it won't run.

The app shows the Default.png but after that it does nothing and just quits the app. Anyone has an idea why?

Comment: Are you running from the simulator or the iPhone itself?  If simulator, check the SDK version number and ensure that it's the same as the target SDK.

Comment: On the iphone itself, SDK versions are the same on all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First stop:  iphone crash logs available via the organizer